# Installing letsencrypt fails when running python install scripts

Tags: installation, python, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to install `letsencrypt` from source on a Debian 8.

When running `./letsencrypt-auto --help --verbose` the script stops at the following lines:

```
...
Collecting funcsigs (from mock->letsencrypt)
  Using cached funcsigs-0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pbr>=0.11 (from mock->letsencrypt)
  Using cached pbr-1.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: pycparser in /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.1.0->cryptography>=0.7->letsencrypt)
Installing collected packages: cryptography, PyOpenSSL, requests, parsedatetime, configobj, pytz, psutil, ndg-httpsclient, werkzeug, funcsigs, pbr, mock, pyrfc3339, acme, zope.event, zope.component, ConfigArgParse, letsencrypt, python-augeas, letsencrypt-apache
  Running setup.py install for cryptography
```

Nothing happens anymore after that. What could be the issue?

Comment: As this stuff is still beta https://community.letsencrypt.org/ is probably a better place right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the cryptography module using pip or package manager. You will probably see errors. By the way! This module is not normally installed on machines with small memory. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt/issues/1081).